# Augmenting Test.QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I want to extend [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) to give me better messages when tests fail (rather than just the seed). For instance, I'd like to be able to create things along the lines of:

```
eqTest :: Eq a => a -> a -> TestResult
eqTest x y = if x == y
             then HappyResult
             else SadResult $ show x <> " /= " <> show y
```

or (with a `Monoid` instance which "stops" on `SadResult` and "continues" on `HappyResult`, akin to a `(&&)` operator for `TestResult`)

```
listEqTest :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> TestResult
listEqTest [] [] = HappyResult
listEqTest [] ys = SadResult $ "Ran out of xs to compare to " <> show ys
listEqTest xs [] = SadResult $ "Ran out of ys to compare to " <> show xs
listEqTest (x:xs) (y:ys) = eqTest x y <> listEqTest xs ys
```

How can I go about extending the QuickCheck functionality? Alternately, is there a randomized testing library which is more extensible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From reading the QuickCheck documentation, the type you are looking for is [`Result`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.6/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#t:Result):

```
data Result
  = MkResult
  { ok          :: Maybe Bool     -- ^ result of the test case; Nothing = discard
  , expect      :: Bool           -- ^ indicates what the expected result of the property is
  , reason      :: String         -- ^ a message indicating what went wrong
  , interrupted :: Bool           -- ^ indicates if the test case was cancelled by pressing ^C
  , abort       :: Bool           -- ^ if True, the test should not be repeated
  , stamp       :: [(String,Int)] -- ^ the collected values for this test case
  , callbacks   :: [Callback]     -- ^ the callbacks for this test case
  }
```

and thanks to the `instance Testable Result` you can use this as the return type of QuickCheck tests:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck Test.QuickCheck.Property> let test xs = if 13 `elem` xs then MkResult (Just False) True "Input contained bad number" False False [] [] else succeeded
Prelude Test.QuickCheck Test.QuickCheck.Property> quickCheck test
*** Failed! Input contained bad number (after 17 tests and 3 shrinks):    
[13]
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks! For some reason, I had the impression that, because the `Result` type was hidden in the main export, I wasn't supposed to use it.